# Type Error with Generic ConsList in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm on Day 2 of TypeScript, so this may be a duplicate question (as I may not know what to search for).

I'm trying to do some basic FP exercises to get familiar with TypeScript. Here I have a standard cons list type with constructors:

```js
type ConsList<T> =
    null |
    [T, ConsList<T>]

function cons<T>(head: T, tail: ConsList<T>): ConsList<T> {
    return [head, tail];
}

function fromArray<T>(arr: Array<T>): ConsList<T> {
    let xs: ConsList<T> = null;
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        xs = cons(arr[i], xs)
    }
    return xs;
}
```

And a foldr:

```js
function foldR<T, U>(
    f: ((x: T, acc: U) => U),
    acc: U,
    xs: ConsList<T>): U {

    if (xs === null) {
        return acc;
    }
    else {
        let [h, t] = xs
        return f(h, foldR(f, acc, t));
    }
}
```

When I try to test the rold, I get an error:

```js
console.log(foldR((a, b) => cons(a, b), null, xs));
```

```
 fold.ts    60  29 error    2322   Type 'ConsList<number>' is not assignable to type 'null'.
   Type '[number, ConsList<number>]' is not assignable to type 'null'. ⮐ (typescript-tide)
```

I'd appreciate pointers on what I'm missing!

Comment: You haven't defined `xs` here; please consider providing a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code here)](https://tsplay.dev/mbdr9w).  Presumably the issue is just that the compiler infers `U` from the type of the passed-in `acc`, which is `null`.  If you want `U` to be inferred as something else you should annotate, specify, or assert a different type, as shown in the linked code before.

Comment: My mistake, and thanks for the pointer to the TypeScript Playground. I had `xs` exactly as you defined it. I'd tried type annotation `let empty: ConsList<number> = null;` which doesn't work, but `let empty = null as ConsList<number>` works. What's the difference?

Comment: @THK See my updated answer.

Comment: @AlexWayne very clear, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your goal, but I see the problem.

Let's start with this function signature:

```
function foldR<T, U>(
    f: ((x: T, acc: U) => U),
    acc: U,
    xs: ConsList<T>
): U
```

Look at `U` specifically. it get's inferred from the argument `acc`, and then used in those other spots.

Now here:

```
foldR((a, b) => cons(a, b), null, xs)
```

You pass `null` for `acc`. So `U` is inferred as `null`.

Now typescript tries to enforce that inference. That takes us to:

```
f: ((x: T, acc: U) => U)
```

Which means `f` is a function that returns `U` (which is inferred as `null`). However, your function returns `ConsList<T>`, which might be `null`, and it might not. The non-null return value is not allowed by the functions type. That's what this error means:

```
Type 'ConsList<T>' is not assignable to type 'null'.
  Type '[T, ConsList<T>]' is not assignable to type 'null'.(2322)
```

`null` is the expected return type, and `ConsList<T>` is the type that is incompatible.

---

To fix this, you need to be able to get `foldR` to infer the correct type for `U`. You have a few ways to do that.

You could cast the `null` value to the correct union type.

```
console.log(foldR(
  (a, b) => cons(a, b),
  null as ConsList<T>,
  xs
));
```

Or you could manually provide the generic parameter types since you know better than is being inferred:

```
console.log(foldR<T, ConsList<T>>(
  (a, b) => cons(a, b),
  null,
  xs
));
```

[Working Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6&ssl=25&ssc=8&pln=21&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM4BkCWTgB4AqA+KAXgCgoyoEBXAG2qgB9TyBtHAGlkVQ23wF1ixAGaUEAY2BpEUMV1x4AFAAsIAQwAmALijsowVWmrb4ydJnkBKY1zO8CAbyZkAThGCVnCKMxUaO+wz4AbmIAX0ERcUlpIWc4AFsAQWdnVRB5BVUU7WTU9PwrTlMeeShHcihqNygADyRrYvN8IgoaahCKoThnKAUq4Cg0FqznADoqhABzYCUoAFooAEYgwag8QigABhW0ObmLMqcK2qQW2WRMlOY0Pg46iyPwo-OkOCrxuEmFLup1ACUFEcyJkOAAjA6EAgvEFQcFsIGtWhQVSnEzcJp4eHHE5HCwWELPLhvCAfL4-f64Dho2zyRQImHgohQrgMixY45UWjsip1XH4wQVVzuTwnEJPSISKRecl-SlQACqdM62gUChq2l0qjEYm08ohBD13OR2t1RrqDXRdkK8sORzQQl6dSIhA2nOoB3K2KgQo8Xi1Yg65HCFQg1CQ0E92P63iU-j4LV5Xu9bl9UCEyg4Mu+HH9-jxgbI4SeQA)

---

> I'd tried type annotation `let empty: ConsList<number> = null;` which doesn't work, but `let empty = null as ConsList<number>` works. What's the difference?

Typescript is a little too smart here. If you do this:

```
const ltr: 'a' | 'b' = 'a'
```

Then typescript knows that `ltr` is `'a' | 'b'`, and also that it should be narrowed to just `'a'` because you assigned assigned it a constant value that is a member of that union. So Typescript tracks that refinement and assumes in that scope that `ltr` can only be `'a'`.

However, when you do this:

```
const ltr = 'a' as 'a' | 'b'
```

Then `'a'` gets casted to some super type that includes `'a'`. The `as` widens the type. And because the widening happens on the right hand side, the widened type is assigned to the variable.